# Honorifics: Is there a proper differentiation between salutation, address and title?

Tags: honorifics, forms-of-address

I'm currently working on technical system which needs to differentiate parts of an honorific. Reading articles and explanations on this subject is a little frustrating as *title*, *address* and *salutation* seem to be used interchangeably for parts with different semantic and are also used to explain each other. Currently I use the following terms:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Salutation ║   Address   ║    Title    ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Dear       ║ Mr / Ms     ║             ║
║            ║ Sir / Madam ║             ║
║            ║             ║ Dr / Doctor ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Sadly this sometimes leads to confusion between the honorific address and the street address in forms.

Is there a formal definition?

Comment: Titles could be Dr., Prof., Capt., etc. Salutation goes like, Dear Sir, Respected Madam, even Hi friends; Address is what takes your envelope to its destination.  If you refer to the way one addresses the audience, it goes like 'how do you address your friends, students, colleagues etc., personally and/or professionally' where your relationship with the audience matters.

Comment: Do you actually need to separate these ways of addressing people for analytical reasons or are you just using them to construct the salutation correctly? For instance in the cases of "Mr John Jones", "Dr John Jones" and "Professor John Jones" the salutation has the same form (Dear 《title》 Jones) but in the case of "Sir John Jones" the salutation should be "Dear Sir John" so just concatenating title and surname would give you the wrong form. Similarly "Dear Sir" (or Madam) is used without a surname at all when the recipient is unknown.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603546/2085).